# How can i make a horizontal scrollbar if the user sizes the browser size?

Tags: html, css

html code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            #primaryContent{
                text-align: center;

            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body id="twoColLayout">
        <div id="primaryContent">
            <img src="banner_1.png" /><img src="banner_2.jpg" /><img src="banner_3.png" />

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

and this is the result.

[image]

ok this works fine, but if make the browser smaller,

it goes like this,

[image]

how can i make a scrollbar, not placing down the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `min-width` property to achieve what you are looking for.

For Instance, let us assume that each of your image is 300px wide, so your `#primaryContent` that contains the images should be greater than 300px * 3 of the total width of all the three images.

```
#primaryContent{
    min-width:950px;
}
```

This will create a horizonatal scroll bar once the browser is stretched to 950px or less.

***PS:** 950px is an arbitary value. Calculate its width according to your requirements.*

**[READ MORE HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width)**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your `body` to a specific width.

So add `width` to your CSS:

```
<style>
    body {
        width: 1000px;
    }

    #primaryContent{
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

Change `1200` to whatever size you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a `min-width` on your container that is enough for the content.
Here is the demonstration [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VbdwN/1/).

Comment: [Agreed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374673/how-can-i-make-a-horizontal-scrollbar-if-the-user-sizes-the-browser-size/20374828#20374828)

Answer (score 0):

try this in your stylesheet...

```
#primaryContent { overflow:scroll; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Images are inline elements. They are wrapped like words if the parent element is not wide enough.

To disable the wrapping use:

```css
#primaryContent {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5f9Vf/) how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Set the primaryContent div to not allow content wrapping by setting white-space:pre

See my jsbin demo [here](http://jsbin.com/IwiDosES/2/edit)

```
    <style>
        #primaryContent{
            text-align: center;
            white-space: pre;
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I miss understood so ignore previous answer
If you want to make horizontal scroll bar you have to use below property in css

```
#primaryContent {
  min-width:1000px; /*you can set whatever width you want to keep*/
}
```

Comment: This would make the images each a third of the width. OP wants the content to overrun horizontally making the overall width wider.